# Two factor authentication with sms and email in asp.net core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, two-factor-authentication

Asp.net core 2.0 includes two factor authentication only with an authenticator app. Is there a way we can re-introduce 2 factor authentication using sms and email too as available in previous versions.

Comment: This is under development. You can check the status here: https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/4469 .